# argument error when I am trying to use keras to tokenize my txt string array

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, tokenize

I am trying to tokenize my string array, and convert them into a formal sequences. however, when I trying to run the following codes, I got an error.

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=20000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(txt)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(txt)
```

Here is my error message:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_words'
```

Can someone tell me why? How should I fix it? Also, my the length of my txt array is about 5000, and the first of 10 string look like this:

['With that said I am getting the flu vaccine this year and I would encourage anyone who is around elderly or children to get it as well', "RT @EWJJr: Difference between bird flu & swine flu: For bird flu you get tweetment. For swine flu you get oinkment. /That's so bad it's good", 'Illinois getting swine flu vaccine within 4 weeks ', "RT @EWJJr: Difference between bird flu & swine flu: For bird flu you get tweetment. For swine flu you get oinkment. /That's so bad it's good", "You gotta be kidding me.. everyone around me is sick, I've joked about getting sick and laughed at flu shots... I'm hurting right now.. Blah", 'Took Ash for her physical and we all got stuck getting the flu shot!!! WTF?', 'RT @WatchBirds Bird News: Missoula waterfowl tested for bird flu', 'Getting my flu shot then babysitting.', 'i know it\'s not "swine flu"! no urge to to poop in the mud and roll around in it. NOT "bird flu"- no poopin\' on windshields or statues.', '@thatoneguybob i know i am scared i am gonna get the swine flu']``

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that you are using Keras 1.x. Upgrading to Keras 2.x should fixed it.